# ios swift post image to linkedin

Tags: ios, swift, image, post, linkedin-api

I am using Swift 3 and the LinkedIn APIs to post an image to LinkedIn.

The code works when I post an image via an http URL.  But, the image is not transferred when I use a URL, NSURL, or String that contains the path to a local file on my iPhone.

Here is the code that represents the data being passed:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
  "content": [
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Description",
    "submitted-url": "https://www.google.com",
    "submitted-image-url": --- This parameter is the problem --
  ],
  "comment": "comment",
  "visibility": [
    "code": "anyone"
  ]
]
```

Here are the values I have used for "submitted-image-url":

1. "https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg"

   - THIS WORKED - referencing a URL on the web
2. "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9BFF81E8-DFE4-41EF-B25C-A82C79CF1708/tmp/yellopost.jpeg"

   - Using this as a String posts all the data to LinkedIn, except the image
3. "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9BFF81E8-DFE4-41EF-B25C-A82C79CF1708/tmp/yellopost.jpeg"

   - This fails
4. "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9BFF81E8-DFE4-41EF-B25C-A82C79CF1708/tmp/yellopost.jpeg" AS AN NSURL

   - This fails

So, how do I reference an image stored on the iPhone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The API only accepts remote URLs. How will the backend access the image otherwise ?

E.g:

```
{
  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
  "content": {
    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
    "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
    "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan.   Unfortunately, the app I am creating is one that will run on the iPhone, with no remote server involved.  The images come from what is stored on the user's phone or from pictures that are taken at the moment.  So, no remote server is involved.   Is there no way to disguise a local path to an image on the iPhone as a remote URL?